# Error encountered after executing a print list statement in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am new to Python and I am facing a weird issue with my code. Following is the part of my code where I am having the problem. The code is fetching a csv file and storing it to an array.

```
import requests

objNSEResponse = requests.get("https://www.nseindia.com" , headers = { "Referer":"https://www.nseindia.com" , "User-Agent":"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"})
objNSECookieJar = objNSEResponse.cookies

objNSEResponse = requests.get("https://www.nseindia.com/api/reportGSM?csv=true" , headers = {"Referer":"https://www.nseindia.com" , "User-Agent":"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"} , cookies = objNSECookieJar)

arrNSEGSMList = map(lambda arrNSEGSMRecord : arrNSEGSMRecord.replace("\"","").split(","), objNSEResponse.content.decode("utf-8-sig").replace("\n\"","\"").split("\n"))

print(list(arrNSEGSMList))

# delete unnecessary values
arrNSEGSMList = numpy.array(list(arrNSEGSMList1))
arrNSEGSMList = numpy.delete(arrNSEGSMList, [0], axis=0)        # delete header row
arrNSEGSMList = numpy.delete(arrNSEGSMList, [2,3,4], axis=1)    # delete all columns except stock symbol and serial number
```

Whenever I insert the statement : `print(list(arrNSEGSMList))` , I get "IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0" at the following statement : `arrNSEGSMList = numpy.delete(arrNSEGSMList, [0], axis=0)`. Zero length numpy array get created due to this print statement.  If I remove the print statement then everything executes without any problem. I get the data which I require in the array "arrNSEGSMList". I am not able to figure out the reason for it.

Comment: You're apparently trying to read CSV – why not use the `csv` module..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond the actual issue caused by `map` being an iterator (as answered by the other answer):

- Since you're parsing CSV data, you should probably use the built-in `csv` module instead of stripping quotes and splitting lines by hand.
- Also, if you use a [Requests Session](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) to make your requests, you don't need to deal with cookies yourself. It's also easier to set default headers.
- Thirdly, there's no need to use Numpy arrays to slice the data; just regular list comprehensions and slices will do.

Here's a reformulation of your code using these:

```
import requests
import csv

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)",
    "Referer": "https://www.nseindia.com",
}
with requests.Session() as sess:
    sess.headers.update(headers)
    sess.get("https://www.nseindia.com/").raise_for_status()
    resp = sess.get("https://www.nseindia.com/api/reportGSM?csv=true")
    resp.raise_for_status()
    # The encoding of the response is actually utf-8-sig,
    # so we force the attribute here so `resp.iter_lines()`
    # works as it should.
    resp.encoding = "utf-8-sig"  
    content = list(csv.reader(resp.iter_lines(decode_unicode=True)))

# `[1:]` slices the header line off.
symbol_and_serial = [(r[0], r[1]) for r in content[1:]]
for symbol, serial in symbol_and_serial:
    print(symbol, serial)
```

This prints out

```
1 ADROITINFO
2 ALPSINDUS
3 ANTGRAPHIC
4 ASIL
```

etc.

Comment: Wow! I am learning new things in python today. Thanks a lot

Comment: Can I use for loop or if statement inside the with statement? ( I don't know if my question makes any sense ). I have to download a file which is generated for previous day when the stock exchange is open. So the file name varies. Presently I generate the file name ( contains date for which it is generated ) in a loop and then send the request. Then i check for the response. Also in one case the file is in zip format containing one csv and one xml file.

Comment: Yes – it's just [a context manager block](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) to ensure that the requests Session closes any lingering connections. I'd suggest wrapping these different data fetching routines into different functions.

Comment: Since I am making multiple requests to same website (different URLs) and creating arrays/lists from each response (csv and zips files). Is it a good idea to put the entire code inside one "with statement". Including the code for creating arrays/lists? Or should I start new session for each request? Thanks

Comment: Depends on the app. For a larger project that will do multiple requests to the same places, not closing the session makes sense for better performance.

Comment: Hi! If it's ok with you then can you please take a look at my new question?

Answer (score 2):

The use of [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) in the statement

```
arrNSEGSMList = map(lambda arrNSEGSMRecord : arrNSEGSMRecord.replace("\"","").split(","), objNSEResponse.content.decode("utf-8-sig").replace("\n\"","\"").split("\n"))
```

makes `arrNSEGSMList` an *iterator* that can be iterated through *once*.  The first call of `list(arrNSEGSMList)` consumes the iterator, so when you try to  execute `list(arrNSEGSMList)` the second time, all the items in `arrNSEGSMList` have already been consumed and you get an empty list.

Here's a similar example:

```
In [18]: m = map(len, ['abc', 'def', 'gh', 'ij'])  # Create a map iterator

In [19]: m
Out[19]: <map at 0x11efb9730>

In [20]: type(m)
Out[20]: map

In [21]: list(m)  # Create a list by iterating through the iterator.
Out[21]: [3, 3, 2, 2]

In [22]: list(m)  # The iterator has already been consumed.
Out[22]: []
```

A fix is to write

```
arrNSEGSMList = list(map(lambda arrNSEGSMRecord : arrNSEGSMRecord.replace("\"","").split(","), objNSEResponse.content.decode("utf-8-sig").replace("\n\"","\"").split("\n")))
```

so you convert the `map` to a list just once.  Or even better, replace the use of `map` with a list comprehension (as suggested by @AKX in a comment):

```
arrNSEGSMList = [record.replace("\"","").split(",") for record in objNSEResponse.content.decode("utf-8-sig").replace("\n\"","\"").split("\n")]
```

From then on, just use `arrNSEGSMList` to use the list.  E.g.

```
print(arrNSEGSMList)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and thank you for the solution. I guess I did not understand the working map function properly. But I think I got it now. Thanks once again.

Comment: It would be more pythonic to use a list comprehension than a `list(map(lambda` construct: `arrNSEGSMList = [record.replace("\"","").split(",") for record in objNSEResponse.content.decode("utf-8-sig").replace("\n\"","\"").split("\n")]`

Comment: This is also a great idea. Thanks.